# I want to keyframe the visibility for many objects with a script without it erasing my current animations

Tags: animation, scripting, keyframes

First post here. I think this is a bit of a tricky one.
I have created many rigid bodies from particles using a physics add-on. Now I want to make the rigid bodies become visible just before their individual animations. (It is a moving machine-gun, dumping cartridges)

I have found and modified a script that keyframes the visibility at intervals but unfortunately it erases the previous movement animations of the objects.
How can i script it to another "animation channel" so to speak?

```
ob = bpy.context.active_object
#assert ob.animation_data is None      #assume it's not animated yet
cur_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
col = bpy.data.collections.get("CRBCollection")
                  
for ob in col.objects:
            ob.select_set(True)   
            obj=ob
            
            ob.animation_data_create()                        
            ac = bpy.data.actions.new('Visibility Action')
            ob.animation_data.action = ac
            fc = ac.fcurves.new(data_path='hide_viewport')  
            fc.keyframe_points.add(2)
            fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set('co', [cur_frame,  0  ,      10,   1])  #frame 0 = show, frame 10 = hide
                    
            cur_frame += 1 # puts in the next keyframe.
            print(cur_frame)
```

Is the ob.animation.data.create() writing over my previous animation?

Any other better method to solve both the: consecutive showing up of, and then animating rigid bodies would be very welcome :D

Thanks in advance, Gus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily add keyframes on "hide_viewport" like this without harming any other animation:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object
#assert ob.animation_data is None      #assume it's not animated yet
cur_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

ob.select_set(True)   
cube=ob


cube.hide_viewport = True
cube.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = 5)  

cube.hide_viewport = False
cube.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = 10)      


cube.hide_viewport = True
cube.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = 15)  

cube.hide_viewport = False
cube.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = 20)
```

result with simple move animation

[image]

Requisition: you have to select an object before running the script.

Comment: Thank you! I saw this method but could not get it to work earlier. It works well now but it seems to start all my objects in hidden/unhidden state even though I for loop everything through "cur_frame".

Comment: It all depends on your first keyframe. If it starts with „True“ - means hidden - they start hidden. Just add a keyframe with 0 and false.